# Is there a name for when a 'c' becomes an [s] sound in words like rusticity, when originally it was a 'c' in rustiC?

Tags: phonology, terminology, morphology

I know it's a sound change, but is there a specific name for it? It's for an assignment I'm writing on the phonological transparency of the suffix -ity.

Answer (score 11):

This question is a bit complicated. -ity is not really a productive suffix in English; it is the English outcome of the Latin suffix -itas. In the transition from Latin to Romance the sound represented by the letter “c”, if followed by a high front vowel, becomes first /ts/ and then, in French and in the French and Latin loan words in English, /s/. So there is not a direct shift from /k/ to /s/, but a staged shift of /k/ > /ts/ > /s/. This can be called affrication followed by de-affrication.

Comment: I think _/k/ > /ts/_ is actually _/k/ > /kʲ/ > /ts/_, with the first stage commonly referred to as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages#Palatalization

Comment: @Quassnoi. This is one of several possibilities. The details are not entirely clear.

Answer (score 9):

The specific process that you are referring to is called "Velar Softening".

Answer (score 4):

A quite generic term for this phenomenon is [Alternation](https://en.wikipedia.org/Alternation_(linguistics)) and since it involves consonants, you can also say *consonant alternation*.

Comment: this particular alternation might also be called palatalisation although, seeing as neither sound is palatal any more this is kinda misleading and not necessarily a great choice unless discussing it from a diachronic pov